# When can one use web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature() and web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall()?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Does the smart contract containing the function to be encoded have to be deployed first before one can use `web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature()` and `web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall()` for a certain function in the deployed smart contract? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the [abi](https://blog.chain.link/what-are-abi-and-bytecode-in-solidity/#:%7E:text=ABIs%20are%20application%20binary%20interfaces,interact%20with%20that%20smart%20contract.) (*compiling the smart-contract*) is enough (*or manually entering the metadata of a function*)

```js
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature({
    name: 'myMethod',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: 'myNumber'
    },{
        type: 'string',
        name: 'myString'
    }]
})
```

```js
> 0x24ee0097
```

```js
web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'myMethod',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: 'myNumber'
    },{
        type: 'string',
        name: 'myString'
    }]
}, ['2345675643', 'Hello!%']);
```

```js
> 0x24ee0097000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008bd02b7b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000748656c6c6f212500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you are not using a compiled ABI but a hardcoded one as above you don't need the contracts to be compiled, you can use as mentioned above.

As an answer, To do these operations smart contract deployment is not essential, compilation is sufficient. These functions are using off-chain encoding and hashing functions to get the relevant output, and these functions do not interact with a smart contract.